# Highlighting select cells in Access crosstab query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

When I run the following statement I get the error: Syntax error in transform statement.
Can someone tell me how I might be able to fix it?

```
TRANSFORM First([H_Project Calender Concat].[Project ID]) AS [FirstOfProject ID]
SELECT [H_Project Calender Concat].Year, [H_Project Calender Concat].Month, [H_Project Calender Concat].Employee
FROM [H_Project Calender Concat]
GROUP BY [H_Project Calender Concat].Year, [H_Project Calender Concat].Month, [H_Project Calender Concat].Employee
PIVOT [H_Project Calender Concat].Day In IIf([H_Project Calender Concat].Month = 1, (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31), (IIf([H_Project Calender Concat].Month = 2, (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)));
```

It continues through all 12 months, and it does not contain a leap year.

**UPDATE:**

I am attempting to create a calendar which shows project ID's that are assigned for certain days.

Example Data:

```
Name |   Date    | Project ID
Bill | 1-29-2014 |   P363 
Jack | 2-03-2014 |   P444
...  |    ...    |   ...
Tom  | 3-30-2015 |   P363
```

When I posted this I originally wanted it to look like this:

```
Year | Month | Name | 1 | 2 | ... | 28 |  29  |  30  | 31

2014 |   1   | Bill |   |   | ... |    | P363 |      | 
2014 |   2   | Jack |   |   | ... |    
...  |  ...  | ...  |   |   | ... |    |      |      |
2015 |   3   | Tom  |   |   | ... |    |      | P363
```

However I realize that that doesn't make a lot of sense. Instead, is there a way I would be able to display the above but highlight the cells to show that the month has ended on those days?

Example: [~ = Highlighted square]

```
Year | Month | Name | 1 | 2 | ... | 28 |  29  |  30  | 31

2014 |   1   | Bill |   |   | ... |    | P363 |      | 
2014 |   2   | Jack |   |   | ... |    |~~~~~~|~~~~~~|~~~~~
...  |  ...  | ...  |...|...| ... |... | ...  | ...  | ...
2015 |   3   | Tom  |   |   | ... |    |      | P363 |~~~~~
```

I currently have the following code. It successfully creates a crosstab query and places the Project ID's in their correct date:

```
TRANSFORM First([H_Project Calender Concat].[Project ID]) AS [FirstOfProject ID]
SELECT [H_Project Calender Concat].Year, [H_Project Calender Concat].Month, [H_Project Calender Concat].Employee
FROM [H_Project Calender Concat]
GROUP BY [H_Project Calender Concat].Year, [H_Project Calender Concat].Month, [H_Project Calender Concat].Employee
PIVOT [H_Project Calender Concat].Day In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31);
```

Comment: You cannot use IIF with IN. You can build a query in VBA.

Comment: Can you TRANSFORM a field you're not SELECTing?  I'm not even sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're counting days in a month and you have no reference to 30 in your IIF statement.  So, even if you could use IIF in a SQL string, your logic is still flawed.  Can you restructure your question, giving us the desired end result (including some sample records if possible), the layout of your original table (also with a couple sample records), and the code you've tried so far?  We can probably help if we had that info.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the description.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Hughes.  It's a great question, I'm hoping Remou, HansUp and/or Gord Thompson weighes in.  I'll have to chew on it and see if I can figure something out.